# FailedPreconditionError tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Why is this simple code giving error?

```
 inputs = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(2,2))

 tf.global_variables_initializer()     

 with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(inputs))
```

It gives me :

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use  uninitialized value Variable_4
 [[Node: Variable_4/read = Identity[T=DT_DOUBLE, _class=["loc:@Variable_4"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_4)]]
```

Comment: I even tried :   'tf.variables_initializer([inputs])'

Answer (score 4):

`tf.global_variables_initializer()` returns an **operation** that you must execute. This operation, indeed, when initializes the global variables.

Therefore, change that line with:

```
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

and within the session, execute it.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
```

Moreover, it's logically better to do not mix the graph definition and the graph execution.

Define the graph outside the session, then execute the operations. Here's an improved version of your code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

inputs = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(2,2))
init_op =  tf.global_variables_initializer()     

mean_op = tf.reduce_mean(inputs)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    mean_value = sess.run(mean_op)
    print(mean_value)
```

By the way, I suggest you reading the tensorflow getting started page: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/